# ViewPager com conteúdo diferente nas páginas

Tags: java, android

Não consigo criar páginas diferentes com *ViewPager*, peguei um tutorial que explica como usar o componente sem *Fragments*, porém não tem informações que preciso para solucionar esse problema. Segue o código abaixo e o print da tela, na qual só consegui colocar o mesmo layout em todas as páginas.

[image: Print das telas]

**activity_main.xlm:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="mobi.devdev.viewpagers.viewpagerwithoutfragments.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**page_layout.xlm:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layoutFeed">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text01"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("position 0");
    list.add("position 1");
    list.add("position 2");

    mAdapter = new SimplePagerAdapter(this, list);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + i)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTabListener(tabListener)
        );
    }

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**SimplePagerAdapter.class:**

```
public class SimplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private List<String> mList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public SimplePagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
    this.mList = list;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.page_layout, null, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text01);
    tv.setText(mList.get(position));
    container.addView(view, 0);

    View eventos = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tela_eventos, null, false);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutFeed);
    layout.addView(eventos);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

}
```

Alguma dica, tutorial ou solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está instanciando sempre o mesmo layout em cada uma das três páginas (`page_layout.xml`). Para corrigir isso, crie três layouts diferentes (digamos, `layout1.xml`, `layout2.xml` e `layout3.xml`) na pasta `/res/layout` e altere o método `instantiateItem()` para carregá-los assim:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view;
    if (position == 0) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null, false);
    } else if (position == 1 {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null, false);
    } else {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, null, false);
    }
    container.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Tudo certo. Só tem um pequeno grande problema hehe ele destrói a página quando saio para uma página 2 vezes distante,por exemplo, quando estou na pagina 1 e avanço para a 3 o conteúdo da 1 é destruído e recriado quando retorno para ela.. Tem como instanciar a única vez sem destruir?

Comment: Para evitar a destruição, se você estiver trabalhando com 3 views, faça assim no seu view pager: `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Comment: Obrigado! Tudo certo agora.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta e também aquele +1 básico. ;)